# How to convert missing value in csv file to database null value using ADF copy activity?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in Azure Data Factory to take in incoming CSV files and save them to SQL server database, and I use a copy activity to take the wrangled CSV file and call a stored procedure to save it the data base table.

However, it is not unusual that some records in the CSV file have missing value at some columns. Such missing value will fail copy activity and below is the error message:

> ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property '' is invalid: 'Cannot set Column 'col 1' to be null. Please use DBNull instead.'

The copy activity runs correctly when there is no missing value in the incoming data.

Below is the snippet of the stored procedure that fails the execution when encounter missing value(s).

```
INSERT INTO target_table(
    [Id],
    [col 1],
    [col 2],
    [col 3]
)    
SELECT
    [source Id],
    [column 1],
    [column 2],
    [column 3]
FROM source_table
```

**My question is what I can do to convert the missing value in CSV file into a null value that SQL server understand.**

I orignally thought the problem is at the database side, so I created a test table in SQL Server and put some test data intentionally with missing values into a test table, then I run the stored procedure. These records with missing value get saved to the target table correctly. So I realized that the problem lies when the copy activity takes in the CSV file and pass it to the stored procedure, and the missing values didn't get translated well into a null value that SQL Server can understand.

Comment: what do parameters on stored procedure look like?

Comment: Below is the header of the stored procedure:  CREATE PROCEDURE [SaveToDB]
@staging [userDefinedTable] READONLY...
I created a user defined table type called [userDefinedTable] to take in the data from csv file.

Comment: what is the user defined table type definition, best to edit the question to add these additional details so others get all the information without having to read all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataflow activity to set the value as NULL. Below is the approach

- In Dataflow, Source data is taken as in below image.

[image]

- **Derived column transformation** is taken and expression is given as `iifNull(id,toString(null()))`

[image]

- **Result**
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't use data flow activity to save the CSV to database because the SQL Server is in a private network and dataflow activity doesn't support saving to a private network. That is why I use Copy activity.

Comment: Did you give Quote character in dataset settings?

Comment: No, I didn't quote the values. I tried quoting the values and it gave me data type error.

Comment: Can you share the sample source data

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this option in Copy activity ?
[image]

This should do that trick .

Comment: I did tried this and it doesn't help. It turns the missing value to the selected Null value, but SQL Server still complains.

Answer (score 0):

After various attempts, here is my solution to the problem. It is not ideal but it works. The solution is that I created a permament staging table in SQL Server and use the copy actity to transfer the CSV data to this staging table. The trick is to use the insert option in the copy activity (see the picture) instead of using a stored procedure which is what I tried to do previously. [image] It feels like there is some internal mechanism behind the scene between copy activity and SQL server that handles the missing value. Once the data is saved in the staging table in SQL Server, I can easily do whatever I want in the database world and missing value is no longer an issue.